# how to add object c SDK inside a swift framework in swift

Tags: swift

we have a objective c SDK from 3rd party and i m creating a framework kind of thing with this objective c SDK in it for sharing it with merchant.

we want that objective c SDK to be added inside the framework which i m creating so how to achieve this in swift?

Note : Objective c SDK which i want to add has some steps like i have to go to buildPhase -> add add framework inside Embed framework which i cannot do in pods -> target and build Phase since i m not finding the option etc

Comment: what  error you got when you add framework ? just add framework in frameworks

Comment: Understand the requirement frist ,adding framework inside framework we are not able to access the SDK methods inside our framework and at pods level we cannot embed sdk

Comment: Error is we cannot find Moudle SDK methods/Controller